# opening firewall 1433 port to IP address that require a direct connection

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, firewall, sql-server-2008, port, connection

We are upgrading from sql server 2005 to sql server 2008  and windows server 2008 R2.

New server is behind a firewall, we have 30 or so windows XP machines, that will require the port 1433 to be open, because they are old Windows applications that require a direct connection.

Previously the old sql server was on two network, one of which was a private network, and we had a vpn server that would put each of these client machines on that private network.  This setup is no longer available for us.

Is there a way to tunnel all these client machines so that we do not have to punch holes in the firewall?

Comment: You guys decided to tear down the VPN server. How does this mean the setup is no longer available to you? Just put the server up again.

Comment: Otherwise, if you can't put the VPN back up, there's nothing wrong in opening ports that need to be opened.

Comment: The new server is at a new server farm location, we were told we are not going to get a second server to act as a vpn.

Answer (score 3):

You have two options, both of which you have eliminated: tunnel through a VPN or poke a hole in the firewall. So no, without knowing a lot more about your application and network infrastructure, there is no other option.